# WSO2 Api manager Graceful connection pool refresh

Tags: api, wso2, wso2-api-manager, api-gateway

[image: Architecture]

Hi,
the one on top is our architecture. Sometime we have to do maintenance in one of ours K8s Farm so we go in the Super Balancer and we turn off all the traffic on one of the balancer downstream. Let's say we want to switch off farm 1.

We saw that even if we redirect all the traffic off farm 1 in the super balancer, wso2 keep the connection open with farm 1. De facto we can't find a way to shut down farm 1 gracefully, without killing the connections.

Is there a command in wso2 to make it gracefully refresh every connection? Something like the one that is on jboss. This way wso2 make all the REST transaction with farm 1 end at the end of the operation, and renegotiate with the SuperBalancer where to go (farm 2).

Comment: What the connections you observed(DBs, http)? Can you please explain what is inside the farms and where WSO2 is installed?

Comment: they are http connections from wso2 to the kubernetes API.